# Converting mongo console, or RMongo query to rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I am having troubles with RMongo, so I'm trying to convert my work over to rmongodb. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098799/rmongo-dbgetqueryforkeys-returns-na), my query looks like this in the mongo console:

```
db.final.find({},{"ids.myid":1,"org.name":1,"_id":0}).skip(0).limit(5000)
```

And like this in RMongo:

```
dbGetQueryForKeys(db,'final', '{}','{"ids.myid":1,"org.name":1,"_id":0}',skip=0,limit=5000)
```

(The latter is not returning values, but the Mongo console one does work.)

My understanding [from the documentation](https://gist.github.com/Btibert3/7751989#file-rmongodb-tutorial-md) is that it should look something like this in rmongodb:

```
library(rmongodb)
mcon <- mongo.create(host="myurl:port",db="dbname")

fields = mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(fields, "ids.myid", 1L)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(fields, "org.name", 1L)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(fields, "_id", 0L)

cur <-  mongo.find(mcon,"final",fields=fields, limit=5000) # query takes the default null
df <- mongo.cursor.to.data.frame(cur)
```

However, I'm getting:

```
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

What's the correct translation of my original query into rmongodb?

I know my connection is valid, because:

```
mongo.get.databases(mcon)
```

works and displays the correct databases.  However, it seems there may be a problem with how I am calling the collection, because

```
mongo.find.one(mcon,"final")
```

is returning NULL.  This despite `db.final.findOne()` working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace (ns) of your collection is wrong. The name of your db is missing. Try this:

```
cur <-  mongo.find(mcon,"dbname.final",fields=fields, limit=5000)
```

and

```
mongo.find.one(mcon,"dbname.final")
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple, but couldn't spot that.

Answer (score 0):

I also had my buffer construction wrong.

```
fields = mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(fields, "ids.myid", 1L)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(fields, "org.name", 1L)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(fields, "_id", 0L)
```

Should have been

```
buf = mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "ids.myid", 1L)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "org.name", 1L)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "_id", 0L)
fields <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
```

via documentation.